# Unattended chef client installation

Tags: chef

Has anyone tried performing an unattended chef client install - installing chef client from the node itself?

There is not much information provided in the documentation. Also, I don't want chef-solo but chef-client on the node.

Comment: Windows? Or what OS?

Comment: @StephenKing: Linux - RedHat distribution preferably.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. Are you looking to not have a central Chef server? Are you looking to bootstrap a chef client during kickstart?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear from your question which OS you are doing this on and if you are doing it in a stand-alone or chef server environment.

Here are two options for stand-alone install of chef-client:

## [Omnibus installer](https://docs.chef.io/install_omnibus.html)

```
curl -L https://www.chef.io/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

or for a specific version

```
curl -L https://www.chef.io/chef/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -v 12.0.2
```

## [Package install](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-client/)

Example for Ubuntu:

```
wget https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/debian/6/x86_64/chef_12.5.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i chef_12.5.1-1_amd64.deb
```

## [Bootstrap](https://docs.chef.io/install_bootstrap.html)

Knife bootstrap will install the chef-client on a node in a chef server environment.  Bootstrap uses the omnibus installer and then copies the required client configuration from the server.

```
knife bootstrap 123.45.6.789 -x username -P password --sudo
```

## [Unattended Bootstrap](https://docs.chef.io/install_bootstrap.html#unattended-installs)

The chef-client can be installed using an unattended bootstrap. This allows the chef-client to be installed from itself, without using SSH. For example, machines are often created using environments like AWS Auto Scaling, AWS CloudFormation, Rackspace Auto Scale, and PXE. In this scenario, using tooling for attended, single-machine installs like knife bootstrap or knife CLOUD_PLUGIN create is not practical because the machines are created automatically and someone cannot always be on-hand to initiate the bootstrap process.

When the chef-client is installed using an unattended bootstrap, remember that the chef-client:

- Must be able to authenticate to the Chef server
- Must be able to configure a run-list
- May require custom attributes, depending on the cookbooks that are being used
- Must be able to access the chef-validator.pem so that it may create a new identity on the Chef server
- Must have a unique node name; the chef-client will use the FQDN for the host system by default

When the chef-client is installed using an unattended bootstrap, it is typically built into an image that starts the chef-client on boot. The type of image used depends on the platform on which the unattended bootstrap will take place.

Use settings in the [client.rb](http://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html) file—chef_server_url, http_proxy, and so on—to ensure that configuration details are built into the unattended bootstrap process.

A node’s initial run-list is specified using a JSON file on the host system. When running the chef-client as an executable, use the -j option to tell the chef-client which JSON file to use. For example:

```
chef-client -j /etc/chef/file.json --environment _default
```

where `file.json` is similar to:

```
{
  "resolver": {
    "nameservers": [ "10.0.0.1" ],
    "search":"int.example.com"
  },
  "run_list": [ "recipe[resolver]" ]
}
```

You may also want to check out [Provision and Bootstrap AWS instances with Chef](http://distinctplace.com/infrastructure/2013/08/23/provision-and-bootstrap-aws-instances-with-chef/)

Answer (score 1):

I just did this, had to tack it together from a few different StackExchange questions and some blog posts. A lot of info was specific to AWS but I'm not deploying there. Here's a quick summary of what is needed; I assume that chef-client is already installed, and you have access to a chef-server instance.

1. validation.pem placed in /etc/chef
2. client.rb in /etc/chef with these fields:

   `node_name "my_node"
   chef_server_url "https://api.chef.io/organizations/my_org
   validation_client_name "my_org-validator"`
3. first_run.json in /etc/chef with (minimally) this data:

   `{"run_list":["role[base]"]}`
4. A startup script that will run

   `chef-client -j /etc/chef/first_run.json > /tmp/chef_first_run.log`

I configured all of this and saved the disk image. Now when a device running that OS install starts up it automatically registers itself with chef-server and executes the run-list for the role "base". I used Ubuntu Server 16.04 and Chef Client 12.3.0

EDIT: previously this said that first_run.json should contain `run-list`. This has been updated to `run_list` per feedback in the comment.

Comment: Comment posted as answer by [LDK](https://serverfault.com/users/429072/ldk): In the .json it should be run_list or it does not work! Also I had to copy the trusted_certs folder of my workstation to the /etc/chef folder so that the ssl worked.

Answer (score 0):

We do it all the time at AWS - check out the Chef CloudInit config directives here: http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#install-and-run-chef-recipes

Chef removed their PPA awhile ago, so you have to use the omnibus or gem methods - package no longer works.